# Como funciona o content-type no java?

Tags: java, android, web-service, http

Eu vi um vídeo de um cara usando o

```
connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "aplication/x-www-urlencoded");
```

Mas eu não entendi como funciona, principalmente o `"aplication/x-www-urlencoded"`.

Comment: Você está definindo propriedades no cabeçalho de envio HTTP. No caso, você está dizendo que o seu conteúdo é do tipo MIME `application/x-www-urlencoded`. Se quiser um MIME mais amigável, temos o `text/plain`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content-Type é um HTTP Header que identifica qual a estrutura de dados que será enviada/recebida do servidor, e é independente de linguagem.

Nesse caso: Content-Type: application/x-www-urlencoded significa que a estrutura dos dados enviados/recebidos é uma query string de chave=valor separados por &.

Ex:

```
nome=John&sobrenome=Doe
```

Outro exemplo: Content-Type: application/json significa que os dados serão enviados/recebidos seguindo a estrutura JSON:

```
{ "nome": "John", "sobrenome": "Doe"}
```

Mais em: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html